# Create a page that will be used to create a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I have created an 'event' custom post type and now I want to create a page that will allow users to create a custom post type from the front-end.  Is there a standard way of doing this?  I could create a template and then link it to a page that I create manually in the wordpress backend, but I would rather do it programatically if possible.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to allow people to create posts from the front-end? Sure...

[In this answer here I explain a very basic way in which you can achieve this very thing, front-end posts to a post type of your choice.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71386/13418)

Here is a basic example of what you might include in your template file to do so;

(please see original answer for further details)

```
<?php
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == "my_post_type") {

//store our post vars into variables for later use
//now would be a good time to run some basic error checking/validation
//to ensure that data for these values have been set
$title     = $_POST['title'];
$content   = $_POST['content'];
$post_type = 'my_custom_post';
$custom_field_1 = $_POST['custom_1'];
$custom_field_2 = $_POST['custom_2'];    

//the array of arguements to be inserted with wp_insert_post
$new_post = array(
'post_title'    => $title,
'post_content'  => $content,
'post_status'   => 'publish',          
'post_type'     => $post_type 
);

//insert the the post into database by passing $new_post to wp_insert_post
//store our post ID in a variable $pid
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

//we now use $pid (post id) to help add out post meta data
add_post_meta($pid, 'meta_key', $custom_field_1, true);
add_post_meta($pid, 'meta_key', $custom_field_2, true);

}
?>
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<form method="post" name="front_end" action="" >
<input type="text" name="title" value="My Post Title" />
<input type="text" name="content" value="My Post Content" />
<input type="text" name="custom_1" value="Custom Field 1 Content" />
<input type="text" name="custom_2" value="Custom Field 2 Content" />
<button type="button">Submit</button>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_post_type" />
</form>
```

This example is void of any error checking, validation and sanitization. This just exemplifies how to take form data and store it into a post type.

Comment: using your method, I would create a page manually in the WordPress back-end and associate it with a template file?

Comment: Yes, the above code can be placed in a custom template file or any existing theme template file. If it's the former, then you can create a page in the dashboard/backend and associate your newly created template with that page. Alternatively you could name the template file `page-{slug}.php` and that will automatically be used when viewing the page of 'slug' name, for example if you created a page called `submit`, then you could name your template `page-submit.php`, otherwise you can set the template from within the post edit screen. Also include `get_header/footer` calls in your template.

Comment: stupid question: what is $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] for?

Comment: Holds the, server request method, such as if it was a GET request or a POST request, etc. In this instance we are checking to make sure that the request method is a POST request (i.e. someone is actually submitting the form for real).

Answer (score 0):

I've done a handful of projects that utilize something like this, and here's my preferred solution:

1. Create a new php page template within your theme.
2. Use PHP to display a form that passes submitted values to itself, and posts the new data using the WordPress [XML-RPC API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API). Normally, I'd create a new user that can only submit drafts to avoid auto-publishing spam or incorrect details.
3. Create the page/URL where the post will be displayed and use the file you created in #1 as your custom template.
4. Optional: Depending on the complexity of your form and the user interaction you intend to implement, you might also need to setup [custom query variables](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var).